# Setting functionTimeout Property for Azure Function Doesn't Seem To Update Timeout

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a local `Azure Function` that listens to a `Service Bus Queue`. I'm using Consumption plan for development, and put in  `"functionTimeout": "00:09:00"` in `host.json` and `local.host.json` as there's some database work that takes longer than 5 minutes in total. However, that value isn't being updated and the function is retrying after about 5 minutes.

I turned off the function in Azure so that I could run the function locally and hit breakpoints, so I'm not sure why the updated `functionTimeout` wouldn't be acknowledged locally. Do I still need to push the code changes to Azure, even with the function currently turned off there? I found another answer here on SO, but the OP is posting to Azure, where I'm just running locally for testing now. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I faced the same issue but after deploying it to Azure functions this was working fine. Below is something how my `host.json` looks like.

host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

After deploying it to azure functions, below is the result that I have received after the mentioned time but until then the function was working as expected.

[image]